# System tray icons and dconf-editor in 14.04

Tags: indicator, 14.04, system-tray, dconf

In 12.04 I could use dconf-editor to edit the icons that were visible in the system tray as well as whitelist any applications that I wanted to be up there (such as XChat, Bomgar, Shutter).

This appears to be missing in 14.04.  Is this something that needs to be updated in dconf-editor, or is there a workaround for this?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-trusty
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: this in fact showing some icons in systray, but I don't see any systray field in dconf editor. How can I edit the whitelist field?

Answer (score 2):

Programs need to supply an indicator. Shutter has a tray icon in 14.04. See preferences, behavior:

[image]

xchat and bomgar need to supply this too.

- in USC there are 2 possible packages for xchat:

  ```
  xchat-gnome-indicator
  xchat-indicator
  ```

You need to load it in the XChat-gnome preferences:

[image]

of if you use XChat is is under "alerts":

[image]

Both are added to the tray (see the envelope):

[image]

- and looking for bomgar I found this: http://mirror.bomgar.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xchat-indicator/ Looks like it uses x-chat so this one is covered.

Comment: My xchat preferences looks quite a bit different: http://i.imgur.com/d60eU2Ml.jpg

And I'm confused as to why Bomgar would use xchat.  The xchat-indicator was stock in 14.04, but I installed xchat-gnome-indicator.  Still not getting Bomgar or XChat icons.  There is an XChat icon under the 'messages' icon, but that just loads up a new instance of XChat.

Comment: I figured as much, my point was more so that neither indicator appears to be working.  In 12.04, with XChat I installed the indicator and whitelisted it in dconf-editor and it worked.  Then with Bomgar, I didn't install any indicator, I just added it to the whitelist in dconf-editor and it appeared in my system tray.  Seemed much more efficient/user-friendly/better in every way than the update.

Comment: Ah, yeah the System Tray icon is checked, but it appears as if it's staying inside the "Messages" icon on the system tray.

Comment: Are you currently running 14.04 and XChat?  If so, does Xchat minimize to the system tray?

Comment: Ah, I see where you edited and added above that both are added to the system tray.  But it's inside the 'messages' container.  So yeah, that's horrible/horrid.  The application doesn't minimize there, you can just launch a new instance of XChat from there.  On top of that applications that do have system tray icons in every linux distro aren't visible without an indicator being installed in 14.04.  Seems like really poor design and planning.  Oh well, I appreciate the help.